# How tf.Variable maintains state of the graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to learn tensorflow. I am really confused with the usage of tf.Variable . I know that in machine learning we have to randomly assign weights to the filter. But this can be done with tf.truncated_normal function. Then what is the role of tf.Variable here? Documentation states that tf.Variable maintains the state of graph. What does it mean? If I omit tf.Variable result is same. So what is the role of tf.Variable? Can someone please help me to understand this?

```
`def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
#function call
filter = weight_variable([1,2,2,1])`
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tensorflow`, anything that is created using `tf.Variable()`, will get updated during training in back-propagation, for example, a weight matrix.

Ideally, by default, every `tf.Variable()` becomes trainable unless you specify it `non-trainable` explicitly.

If you do this `initial = tf.truncated_normal([5,10], mean=0, stddev=0.1)`, then tensorflow will not know that it's a trainable variable and hence it will not be trained. It will stay constant throughout the training.